# xNet request problems

Tags: c#, request, xnet

```
HttpResponse response;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.IEUserAgent();
response = request.Post("https://www.site.com", "value=1");
```

But after request, program trys to open file value=1. Why?

Comment: We need some implementation details...what's `request`? Obviously not an `HttpRequest` object

Answer (score 0):

Try this option, code:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.RandomUserAgent();
    request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse("127.0.0.1:1080");

    var reqParams = new StringDictionary();

    reqParams["login"] = "neo";
    reqParams["password"] = "knockknock";

    string content = request.Post(
        "www.whitehouse.gov", reqParams).ToText();

    string secretsGovernment = content.Substring("secrets_government=\"", "\"");
}
```

And read documentation [here](http://xnet.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Post(string address, string path) - send file. You can set the parameters as:

1:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    var reqParams = new RequestParams();

    reqParams["login"] = "neo";
    reqParams["password"] = "knockknock";

    string content = request.Post(
        "www.whitehouse.gov", reqParams).ToString();
}
```

2:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest("www.whitehouse.gov"))
{
    request
        .AddParam("login", "neo")
        .AddParam("password", "knockknock");

    string content = request.Post("/").ToString();
}
```

3:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    var reqParams = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"login", "neo"},
        {"password", "knockknock"},
    };

    var httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(reqParams);

    string content = request.Post(
        "www.whitehouse.gov", httpContent).ToString();
}
```

4:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    string reqStr = "param1=value1&param2=value2";

    string content = request.Post(
        "www.whitehouse.gov", reqStr,
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").ToString();
}
```